# Switching position of bootstrap input-group-addon & input when on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to change the position of bootstrap input-group-addon when on mobile by using two input and playing with their display and visibility. 
From a frontend visibility perspective I got what I want, the input is now behind the addons ... but I'm running some javascript on #input-newsearch and when on mobile it's not working. It looks like it's still looking at the first input. What am I missing or how can I solve this?

html:

```
<div class="input-group">
<input id="input-newsearch" class="form-control input-newsearch-desktop" type="text">                                                                                                                                           
<span class="input-group-addon" id="delete-newsearch">Delete</span>
<span class="input-group-addon" id="remove-newsearch">Remove</span>
<input id="input-newsearch" class="form-control input-newsearch-mobile" type="text">                                                                                                                                                    
</div>
```

css:

```
.input-newsearch-mobile {
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
}   

@media (max-width: 768px){
.input-newsearch-desktop {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;     
}
.input-newsearch-mobile {
    display: initial;
    visibility: initial;        
}           
}
```

javascript:

```
$('#delete-newsearch, #delete-newsearch').on('click', function() { 
$('#input-newsearch').val('');                                          
}); 

$('#input-newsearch').autocomplete({
source:'/source.php',  
minLength: 3,
...
});
```

Comment: Can you please post your JavaScript as well. One thing that could be the culprit is that `display: none;` actually **removes** the element from the DOM, whereas `visibility: hidden` simply hides it. You may want to remove `display: none` in your media query for `.input-newsearch-desktop`, as you won't be able to target the element with JavaScript once it is removed.

Comment: Please see the javascript above. I'm doing a autocomplete on the input und use the buttons for clearing. The .val('') is also not working if I hide the first input element on smaller screens since I want to have the buttons above the input on mobile ... If on desktop everything is working just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Id's as your selection I would use a class instead.

The reason it is not working as you intended is because Id's are expected to only show up once.  It causes problems when you have multiple elements with the same Id and try to reference one of them.

**Styles**

Added the class `input-newsearch`

```
<div class="input-group">
<input id="input-newsearch" class="form-control input-newsearch input-newsearch-desktop" type="text">                                                                                                                                           
<span class="input-group-addon" id="delete-newsearch">Delete</span>
<span class="input-group-addon" id="remove-newsearch">Remove</span>
<input id="input-newsearch" class="form-control input-newsearch input-newsearch-mobile" type="text">                                                                                                                                                    
</div>
```

**Javascript**

Changed Id selector `'#input-newsearch'` to the class `'.input-newsearch'`

```
$('#delete-newsearch, #delete-newsearch').on('click', function() { 
$('.input-newsearch').val('');                                          
}); 

$('.input-newsearch').autocomplete({
source:'/source.php',  
minLength: 3,
...
});
```

Comment: wanted to mention that a better approach would be to have a block of javascript for each input-addon and only calling the associated function based on the window's width.  However, the performance gain is basically 0 so the solution above should be just fine.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  Keep on coding!